# Importing files to mongodb using mongoimport

Tags: python, mongodb

I am still struggling with getting used to mongo and I am trying to use mongoimport to upload 500 json files, each containing. Around 15000 lines, where each line represents a tweet. Is there a way to upload them all at once ? Also, the language i wish to use is python since i only have the jupyter notebook to work with

Comment: Did you chech how to use PyMongo? https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mongodb_getstarted.asp

Answer (score 0):

I thought that is no other way than loop them.

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
  subprocess.Popen(['mongoimport', '--db', 'db_name', '-c','tweets', filename, '--jsonArray', '--upsert','--drop'])...
```

Comment: so do i just replace db_name with th name of the database and that's it ? feels weirdly simple but thanks

Comment: yap, mongoimport do replacement data, it does not merge the data. Is it solve your problem?

Comment: problem is i cannot manually write the names of 576 json files. I would need a loop to iterate over the folder in which all the files are stored. Also, for some reason pyhon cannt find the file

Comment: Also, got it to work for 1 file but some columns, which otherwise have a value inside the json file are listed with value 0 when uploaded to mongo

Comment: I have updated my answer, I do loop the filename from the directory